# How to use a list of numbers from a spreadsheet.csv field in the query of arcpy.Select_analysis

Tags: arcpy, sql, cursor, select-by-attribute, list

Have an excel spreadsheet in CSV format with a field of APN numbers (8 digit US assessor parcel numbers)

[image]

Need to query these in a large layer of parcel polygons using python script and the arcpy.Select_analysis function.

The problem may be the way I created the list object in python.  When I print the list, commas are returned inside parenthesis' with the APN's .

[image]

The error message is `invalid expression`, here is the script I have:

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "D:/Project"
env.overwriteOutput = True

APNlist = []
Plist = "D:/Project/Preserve_Parcels.csv" #change format??
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Plist, ["APN8"])

for row in cursor:
    APNlist.append(row) #should I change how the list is appended?
print APNlist


infc = "D:/Project/Final.gdb/Parcels"
fieldname = "APN_8"
outfc = "D:/Project/Final.gdb/parcels_sel"
qry = """APN_8 IN {0}""".format(str(tuple(APNlist))) # Wrong syntax?


arcpy.Select_analysis (infc, outfc, qry)
```

I'm a python/arcpy beginner

Comment: See the update to my answer below, it should clear up some confusion as there will be a difference in how your query variable is structured  based on if your APN_8 field in `infc` is a string or numeric field.

Comment: GeoSharp, thank you kindly for your help with this and thanks to all other editors.  I have implemented your solution, my infc APN_8 is a string field.  Just two issues for editing: APNlist object is spelled with a lowercase l, and I received a syntax error for    sql_list = ["'" + str(x) "'" for x in APNList]  until I added another + in front of the second single quote like so: sql_list = ["'" + str(x) + "'" for x in APNList]  Then everything worked PERFECT.  Thanks again so much, I'm now a big fan of gis stackexchange.

Comment: Accepted, I tried upvoting but my rep is too low for public display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append to your list with your cursor even though you are only searching one field you still need to index to the first field like this `row[0]`:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Plist, ['APN8']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        APNList.append(row[0])
```

This should fix the tuple issue you are having.

If `APN_8` is a string field in `infc` you can create a correct SQL syntax list and query like this:

```
sql_list = ["'" + str(x) "'" for x in APNList]
sql_list = ','.join(sql_list)
qry = "APN_8 IN (%s)" % sql_list
```

If `APN_8` is a numeric field in `infc` you can create a correct SQL syntax list and query like this:

```
qry = "APN_8 IN (%s)" % str(APNList)[1:-2]
```

By doing either of these, depending on whether `APN_8` is a string or numeric field in `infc`, you will create a comma separated string surrounded by proper SQL syntax for a list `(` `)` which is what you need for the where clause in `arcpy.Select_analysis`, the new string representation of your list will look like this for the first syntax:

```
"('00391711','11006553','11007963','22010643')"
```

and this with the second syntax:

```
"(00391711, 11006553, 11007963, 22010643)"
```

The way you did it, directly supplying the string representation of the python to your query, will make your query contain brackets `[` `]` before and after your list object like this:

```
"[00391711, 11006553, 11007963, 22010643]"
```

The SQL parser that `arcpy.Select_analysis` uses does not know what to do with the `[` `]`.